# Google Sheets + Apps Script: Loop through ID to move files

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi with this code I can move one file at the time what I'm trying to do is get this code to go through my range "C3:C" and move the file that contain the ID from my range "C3:C" so I need to loop through the range I'm just not sure how to do it the proper way any help would great thanks

```
function moveFile(){

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var ws = ss.getSheetByName('sheet1');
var range = ws.getRange('C3:C').getValues();
var ID = "1002";


 
var files = DriveApp.getFolderById('1ixzEPTL9--IDNUMBER--n9WwDa68l').searchFiles("title contains '" + ID + "'" ).next(); 
var name = files.getName();
var file_id = files.getId();
var file_Blob = files.getBlob();
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(file_id);
   
var sourceFileId = file_id;
var destinationFolderId = "1m5J09ODZv--IDNUMBER--knTpewg8f0D";

Drive.Files.update({ parents: [{ id: destinationFolderId }] }, sourceFileId);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to move the files which have the filename including `ID` retrieving from the column "C" using Google Apps Script.

#### Modification points:

- In this case, I would like to suggest the following flow.

  1. Retrieve the file list of the files with the filename including the values of column "C" from the folder `1ixzEPTL9--IDNUMBER--n9WwDa68l`.
  2. Move files to `1m5J09ODZv--IDNUMBER--knTpewg8f0D` using `moveTo` with the file list.

#### Modified script:

```
function moveFile(){
  var sourceFolderId = "1ixzEPTL9--IDNUMBER--n9WwDa68l";  // Please set the source folder ID.
  var destinationFolderId = "1m5J09ODZv--IDNUMBER--knTpewg8f0D";  // Please set the destination folder ID.
  
  // 1. Retrieve the file list of the files with the filename including the values of column "C" from the folder `1ixzEPTL9--IDNUMBER--n9WwDa68l`.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName('sheet1');
  var IDs = ws.getRange('C3:C' + ws.getLastRow()).getValues().filter(([c]) => c.toString() != "");
  var files = [];
  var srcFiles = DriveApp.getFolderById(sourceFolderId).getFiles();
  while (srcFiles.hasNext()) {
    var file = srcFiles.next();
    if (IDs.some(([ID]) => file.getName().includes(ID))) {
      files.push(file);
    }
  }
  
  // 2. Move files to `1m5J09ODZv--IDNUMBER--knTpewg8f0D` using `moveTo` with the file list.
  var destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(destinationFolderId);
  files.forEach(file => file.moveTo(destinationFolder));
}
```

#### Note:

- When there are a lot of files you want to move, the batch request might be suitable. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/batch)

#### References:

- [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)
- [moveTo(destination)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#movetodestination)

Comment: Hi Tanaike thanks for the quick reply I've tried saving the code but it's giving me an syntax error on this line  var IDs = ws.getRange('C3:C' + ws.getLastRow()).getValues().filter(([c]) => c.toString() != ""); but the line looks fine  not sure why i get the error

Comment: @Yvan L Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In that case, can you confirm whether V8 runtime has already been enabled at the script editor? If V8 runtime is not enabled, please enable it and test it again.

Comment: Thanks Tanaike that was the problem now it working I also change the  if (IDs.some(([ID]) => file.getName().includes(ID)))  for  if (IDs.some(([IDs]) => file.getName().includes(IDs))) the s were missing but now it's working perfect thanks for your time